# Data parsing/importing, formatting and exporting using python-2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Currently use pearl to produce a table from a large amount of data and export to excel.

We are looking to switch to a python report system.

Looking for the best way to import/parse data from a .csv or .xls file into python, format that data, print the data in console and export formatted data into a spreadsheet. (By best I mean the simplest/slickest)

Want the ideal output:

% symbol is optional
* can be changed for any other marker except a letter

also want to do more with this data in python after export

Comment: pandas is pretty useful for working with this kind of data, in general. For this specific case, you'll have to manipulate the data a little bit, but pandas could be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should do the job

for python3:

```
import csv
with open("output.csv","w",newline='') as f:
    output = csv.writer(f) 
    for line in csv.reader(open("input.csv")):
        for item in line[2:]:

            #to skip empty cells
            if not item.strip():
                continue

            item = item.split(":")
            print([line[1]+item[0],item[1].rstrip("%")])
            output.writerow([line[1]+item[0],item[1].rstrip("%")])
```

if using python2 replace the second line by

```
with open("output.csv","wb") as f:
```

Comment: Ran this but getting Index out of range error on line 7, any thoughts?

Comment: @user3234810 There is two possibility: possibility 1: either there is empty cells I corrected code to behave well; possibility 2: either there is a cell in the second part of column which don't have a colon in it

Comment: Absoltuley, fantastically amazing. I am very greatful for your help with that, rest of the analysis pipeline works a treat now.